# bash line continuation and comments

Tags: bash

Any explanation why the comment is echo'ed in the third example?

```
$ echo a b \
> c # test
a b c

$ echo a b c \
> # test
a b c

$ echo a b c \
> \ # test
a b c  # test

$ echo a b c \
> \  # test
a b c
```

Comment: There is no comment in the third example, just an argument that contains a `#`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash, `#` starts a comment **only if** it is at the *beginning* of a *word*.  As per this rule, neither of the following  two command lines have comments:

```
$ echo a b c# test
a b c# test
$ echo a b c \ # test
a b c  # test
```

In the first case above, `#` is part of the word `c#` and `#` is not at the beginning.

In the second case above (your case), `#` is part of the word  `#` (where the first character is a blank and `#` is the second character).  `#` is not at the beginning and therefore does not start a comment.

Normally, the shell treats a blank as a word separator.  By escaping the blank, it loses that special interpretation and becomes just another character.

The use or not of a continuation line does not change this.

#### Documentation

From the section entitled Comments in `man bash`:

> a word  **beginning with** # causes that word and all remaining
>   characters on that line to be ignored.  [Emphasis added.]

Answer (score 2):

Seems like  `# test` is the next word/argument and since comments have to start with `#` the third command has no comment.